# Rendering an animation with audio across multiple computers?

Tags: rendering, animation, makehuman, network

For a project, my team and I want to combine our computers' powers to render an animation quickly. We have audio as well as fluid simulations and particle systems in the animation. Is there any way we could render the same animation on our different computers at our different houses and networks, combining it with the audio in the same process? Maybe using a shared drive or something. I have looked into Sheepit render farm already but it will not work for us because of the size of the file and more importantly, it will not enable autorun python scripts, which we need for our character rig. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In my own experience, the best thing to do is to render the frames out via shared render farm across the computers and then after all the rendered frames are done, composite them together and get the color worked out. Once that stage is there, then insert the audio and output the frames and audio as a movie container with the desired compression, etc.

Comment: The fluid sim is going to be your biggest trouble. You are going to have to duplicate the cache files and make sure the paths still work on every computer you want to render on.